# Vim: How to hightlight the data greater than a constant value in a specific column？

Tags: vim, find, highlight, vim-plugin

- For example, I want to hightlight all the data greater than 0.050 in
  "Trans" column.
- All the data are exactly under "Trans" string.
- Thanks a lot.
- DTran     Trans    Incrm
- 0.001     0.050    0.025
- 0.004     0.021    0.014
- 0.007     0.061    0.037
- 0.002     0.103    0.125
- 0.004     0.016    0.042

Comment: Transform into CSV (or Tab-delimited), import into MS Excel or other spreadsheet, then use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small plugin:

```
fu! <sid>HighlightVal(limit)
    if a:limit !~? '^\d\.\d\+$'
        echoerr "Wrong format, expecting floating point number"
        return
    endif
    let startidx = 3 " Start line, where to start looking for
    let endidx   = '$' " end line where to check value
    let content=getline(startidx, endidx)
    let content=map(content, 'str2float(split(v:val, " ")[1])')
    try
        call map(get(w:, 'matches', []), 'matchdelete(v:val)')
    catch
    endtry
    let w:matches = []
    let pat = '^\(\S*\)\s\zs[0-9.]\+'
    for val in content
        if val > str2float(a:limit)
            call add(w:matches, matchadd('WarningMsg', pat.'\%'.startidx.'l'))
        endif
        let startidx+=1
    endfor
endfu
com! -nargs=1 HiVal call <sid>HighlightVal(<q-args>)
```

Put that into your `~/.vim/plugin` folder and, restart Vim and for your data then
call it with `:HiVal 0.05`.

For a real plugin, it needs more error handling (currently, it assumes all lines after line 2 are valid (and have at least two columns and consist only of floats and are not null or empty), so that it would become more robust. But for the purpose here, this should be enough.